# VLCJ load 32 and 64 bit libraries from different folders

Tags: java, vlc, jna, libvlc, vlcj

Im using vlcj for audio and video support in my java program.
I integrated the libvlccore.dll... and the plugin folder into a "VLC" folder in my project, so it even runs if the user has no vlc installation.

But i have to seperate them into a 32 (with vlc 32 bit dll files) and a 64 bit (with 64 bit dll files) version which has to match with the java architecture...
It would be nice if i could include 32 and 64 bit .dll files into one version which check which JRE architecture is used and loads the right dll files. My problem, the plugin folder is ~100 mb big, but it seems that the 4 dll files have to be in the same folder with the plugin folder...
I could make a "32" and a "64" folder including the dll files and the plugin folder but this would lead to a unnecessary copy of the plugin folder...

```
    String testpath = new File("").getAbsolutePath().toString();
    testpath = testpath.replace(".", "");
    testpath = testpath.replace("\\", "//");
    testpath = testpath+"//VLC";
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), testpath+(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("64")?"//64":"//32")); // Get the right dll files when the JRE is 32 / 64 bit...
    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getPluginsDirectoryName(), testpath); // This doesn´t seem to have any effect.         
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
```

I get the error:

```
main libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.
```

Is there a way to load the dll files and the plugins without having them in the same folder?

My folders look like:

```
"\\VLC"
.."\\plugins"
.."\\32"
...."libvlccore.dll"
...."axvlc.dll"
...."libvlc.dll"
...."npvlc.dll"
.."\\64"
...."libvlccore.dll"
...."axvlc.dll"
...."libvlc.dll"
...."npvlc.dll"
```

Comment: Note: a 32-bit process can only load 32-bit DLLs and if you have 64-bit DLLs it will be as if they are not there.  Same for a 64-bit process loading a 32-bit DLL. As such you can't share common DLL between 32-bit and 64-bit as they have to be different. There is no alternative to having a copy of all the DLLs needed for each platform as they can't be the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can rename dlls as libvlc..32.dll and libvlc..64.dll. Inside your code check environment programmatically if 32-bit or 64-bit then load your dlls accordingly by using System.loadLibrary or System.load not NativeLibarary.It is not recommended but it may work.

Comment: It is almost working but when i rename the dll files and load them then they cant find their dependencies anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do this

1. Make the same folder and file structure just as you did.
2. Then on every startup of the application, have it check for 32bit or 64bit architecture
3. Copy the appropriate dll files to the plugins folder. But right before doing this, check first if the dll files do not exist. If the dll files exist in the plugin folder but they are not the correct files, then replaced them.

I'm assuming that the actual copying of dll files to the plugin folder does not happen everytime the application is opened because it shall be done only during the first time the application is launched or when the user changes the JRE from 32bit to 64bit or vice versa. So there's no considerable delay during startup most of the time.

Comment: Im actually doing it this way at the moment and it works, but its not the cleanest solution.

Comment: Well I think this one may be better than most of the other applications since it can run both 32bit and 64bit. Other applications need separate installers. You can also implement like the other applications with two types of installers. That may be more cleaner. Or maybe, you can create just a single installer that contains the files for both 32bit and 64bit. And during the installation, your installer will decide which one to install. The resulting installed app would be similar to other applications. It's pure 32bit or pure64bit. Even the Java software does not merge 64bit and 32bit.

Comment: I don't see the point of copying the files, just have both sets of files in their own directories and at run-time change the directory they're loaded from - I think it should just work by setting the native library search path (courtesy of JNA), or if you need to you can use the VLC_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable

Comment: @caprica I think that was what the OP was orinally trying to do. But he encountered errors. If you can provide him with a workable implementation of your idea, then that's the best answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ship 32-bit and 64-bit versions of LibVLC, LibVLCCore, and all of the plugins.

So have two directories, call them what you want, "32" and "64" will do as an example.

Put the entire installation of the 32-bit VLC, including the 32-bit plugins directory, and maintaining the entire directory structure, into "32".

Put the entire installation of the 64-bit VLC, including the 64-bit plugins directory, and maintaining the entire directory structure, into "64".

When you run your application, at run-time determine which architecture you need, and then point JNA/vlcj at the appropriate one.

There are a number of ways how to do this, the simplest is something like:

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "your-app-dir/32");
```

Or

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "your-app-dir/64");
```

I don't think it needs to be any more complicated than that.

As long as you kept the same directory structure, LibVLC should find the plugins automatically under its own directory.

If you still have problems, you can try setting the system environment variable VLC_PLUGIN_PATH to point to the right plugins directory - but this should not be necessary.

Remember as well that you must match the CPU architecture of the JVM with your VLC installation.

Also this likely won't work on Linux as you can't just copy shared object files around without affecting run-time linking.